# Adding custom post thumbnails to wordpress theme sidebar without plugins

Tags: php, wordpress, thumbnails

I used this code to sidebar.php file to get recent posts thumbnails:

```
<ul id="popular-comments">

<?php $pc = new WP_Query('orderby=$current_post&posts_per_page=5'); ?>

<?php while ($pc->have_posts()) : $pc->the_post(); ?> <li>

<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(array(75,75)); ?></a> <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>

<p>Posted by <strong><?php the_author() ?></strong> on the
    <?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?> with
    <?php comments_popup_link('No Comments;', '1 Comment', '% Comments'); ?></p> </li>

<?php endwhile; ?> </ul>
```

it worked fine but I want to tweak it to add unique thumbnail for each category. For example : I will create a folder in my theme directory named images then add thumbnail for each category so that my sidebar dynamically inherits post thumbnails from this folder ( Note : I am using child theme ) can anyone tweak the code for me OR come with another trick to do so?

Comment: If I read your question right, you want to add thumbnails to categories.  We've used [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/categories-images/) successfully in the past.

Comment: thank you, I know that plugin the problem is that I'm developing theme for client and he doesn't want to use plugins

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to stuff all the functionality into the theme. For example: what happens when the client activates a new theme? Check for example [this article](http://wp.tutsplus.com/articles/general/functionality-plugins-vs-themes/) on the matter.

Comment: I'm not adding any functions It's like  a WordPress loop in the sidebar to get recent posts with unique thumbnail for each category form folder I made in the theme directory. I just want to tweak the above code to get the job done! any ideas??

Comment: any help? I need this so bad!